# variables in dictionaries in python

Tags: python, variables, dictionary, nan

I am trying to create a DataFrame using a Dictionary in which I have added variables as values..

```
gpa_min = df_gpa.min()
gpa_Q1 = df_gpa.quantile(0.25)
ratio_gpa = 'gpa ratio Q1/outlier is ', df_gpa.quantile(0.25)/df_gpa.min(), 'should be'
gre_min = df_gre.min()
gre_Q1 = df_gre.quantile(0.25)   
ratio_gre = 'gre ratio Q1/outlier is ', df_gre.quantile(0.25)/df_gre.min()

index = ['gre','gpa']
columns = ['min','Q1','Q1/min']


outlier = pd.DataFrame({"gre": [gre_min,gre_Q1,ratio_gre],
                        "gpa": [gpa_min,gpa_Q1,ratio_gpa]},
                       index = index, columns = columns)
print outlier
```

this runs with no error, but the answer is Data Frame with only ´Nan´ values... this is very confusing, as if I just called the variables created above ('gre_min, gre_Q1, ratio_gre, gpa_min, gpa_Q1, ratio_gpa') I get the values correctly

I am using Python 2.7

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want the final dataframe to look like? You specify 2 columns in the dictionary, but three in 'columns'

Comment: I want two rows ('gre' , 'gpa') and three columns ('min','Q1','Q1/min')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building a pandas `DataFrame` this way will assume that the dictionary you're passing in is the dictionary of *columns* of the dataframe... But your subsequent definition of the `index` and `columns` are inconsistent with that. Pandas then tries to be smart, basically 'interpolates' your data on the provided indices/columns. Except since it has none (your 'data' columns and 'textual' columns are completely unrelated: in my example below, it tries to get columns `x`, `y` and `z` from columns `gre` and `gpa`), it just spits out `NaN`s

```
In[70]: pd.DataFrame({'gre': [1,2,3], 'gpa': ['a', 'b', 'c']}, index=['gre', 'gpa'], 
         columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
Out[70]: 
       x    y    z
gre  NaN  NaN  NaN
gpa  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Flipping your rows/columns gets you what you want:

```
In[71]: pd.DataFrame({'gre': [1,2,3], 'gpa': ['a', 'b', 'c']}, columns=['gre', 'gpa'], 
         index=['x', 'y', 'z'])
Out[71]: 
   gre gpa
x    1   a
y    2   b
z    3   c
```

Or simpler still, let it infer the column names from the dictionary keys:

```
In[72]: pd.DataFrame({'gre': [1,2,3], 'gpa': ['a', 'b', 'c']}, index=['x', 'y', 'z'])
Out[72]: 
  gpa  gre
x   a    1
y   b    2
z   c    3
```